# How to install an apps from internal storage while being not allowed in android?

Tags: android, installation, overlay, android-install-apk

I have developed a small utility application with an overlay view. Problem is, after installing my application on the device, I cannot install any other apk from the internal storage. I can install applications from google play, and via ADT. But it don't let me install from my own internal storage. I am out of ideas. Couldn't find a way to solve this problem. Please help me out with ideas and workable codes. Thanks in advance.
Here is the Menifest file I am using.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com._"
    android:versionCode="9"
    android:versionName="1.5" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/winar"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.TransPerantActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.MyService"
            android:process=":my_process" >
        </service>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.NetworkChangeReceiver"
            android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name="com.waltonbd.networkmonitor.Update"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_update" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.waltonbd.networkmonitor.About"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Help"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_help" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
FileOutputStream fos;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    fos = mContext.openFileOutput("New.apk",mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
} else {
    fos = mContext.openFileOutput("New.apk",Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
}
```